# How can I know/list the properties of any application macOSX to be able to use osascript/apple-script?

Tags: scripting, application, apple

I'm a newbie for `osascript`. I want to code some automated script/apple-script.

I've searched and tried some tutorials about apple-script but it's a simple application like "Reminders" "Finder". I want to know how can I list properties of any other application like "Slack" or any other so that I can know what I can do with apple-script more.